# How to get specific data pieces from laravel collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I want to simulate the same thing as in `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` and your data can be shown by `echo $row['name']` OR `echo $row['mobile_number']`.
In laravel, what I managed to pull is;
`$users= DB::table('users')->get();
echo $users;`

For now, the data shown is in array and I only want certain field to only be shown, how do I do that?
For example, I only want name and mobile number from the users table, I tried `$users->('name')` but it shows an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$users= DB::table('users')->get();

foreach($users as $user)
{
    echo $user->name;
}
```

**Note:** before applying `foreach()` make sure `$users` have an array/object with at-least one value in it like:

```
if(count($users) > 0)
{
    // loop here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this -

```
$users= DB::table('users')->select('name', 'mobile_number')->get();

if($users != null){
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        echo $user->name;
        echo $user->mobile_number;

    }
}
```